# Voyager - Specific Columns to be displayed on browse

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I am trying to display some specific column headers on browse, I have customised the controller and model, and also have made some changes to `index()` inside my customised controller.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // GET THE SLUG, ex. 'posts', 'pages', etc.
    $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

    // GET THE DataType based on the slug
    $dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    // Check permission
    $this->authorize('browse', app($dataType->model_name));

    $getter = $dataType->server_side ? 'paginate' : 'get';

    $search = (object) ['value' => $request->get('s'), 'key' => $request->get('key'), 'filter' => $request->get('filter')];
    $searchable = $dataType->server_side ? array_keys(SchemaManager::describeTable(app($dataType->model_name)->getTable())->toArray()) : '';
    $orderBy = $request->get('order_by', $dataType->order_column);
    $sortOrder = $request->get('sort_order', null);
    $usesSoftDeletes = false;
    $showSoftDeleted = false;
    $orderColumn = [];
    if ($orderBy) {
        $index = $dataType->browseRows->where('field', $orderBy)->keys()->first() + 1;
        $orderColumn = [[$index, 'desc']];
        if (!$sortOrder && isset($dataType->order_direction)) {
            $sortOrder = $dataType->order_direction;
            $orderColumn = [[$index, $dataType->order_direction]];
        } else {
            $orderColumn = [[$index, 'desc']];
        }
    }

    // Next Get or Paginate the actual content from the MODEL that corresponds to the slug DataType
    if (strlen($dataType->model_name) != 0) {
        $model = app($dataType->model_name);
        if ($dataType->scope && $dataType->scope != '' && method_exists($model, 'scope' . ucfirst($dataType->scope))) {
            $query = $model->{$dataType->scope}();
            dd($query);
        } else {
            // $query = $model::select('*');
            $query = $model::select('id', 'owner_name');

        }

        // Use withTrashed() if model uses SoftDeletes and if toggle is selected
        if ($model && in_array(SoftDeletes::class, class_uses($model)) && app('VoyagerAuth')->user()->can('delete', app($dataType->model_name))) {
            $usesSoftDeletes = true;

            if ($request->get('showSoftDeleted')) {
                $showSoftDeleted = true;
                $query = $query->withTrashed();
            }
        }

        // If a column has a relationship associated with it, we do not want to show that field
        $this->removeRelationshipField($dataType, 'browse');

        if ($search->value != '' && $search->key && $search->filter) {
            $search_filter = ($search->filter == 'equals') ? '=' : 'LIKE';
            $search_value = ($search->filter == 'equals') ? $search->value : '%' . $search->value . '%';
            $query->where($search->key, $search_filter, $search_value);
        }

        if ($orderBy && in_array($orderBy, $dataType->fields())) {
            $querySortOrder = (!empty($sortOrder)) ? $sortOrder : 'desc';
            $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([
                $query->orderBy($orderBy, $querySortOrder),
                $getter,
            ]);
        } elseif ($model->timestamps) {
            $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([$query->latest($model::CREATED_AT), $getter]);
        } else {
            $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([$query->orderBy($model->getKeyName(), 'DESC'), $getter]);
        }

        // Replace relationships' keys for labels and create READ links if a slug is provided.
        $dataTypeContent = $this->resolveRelations($dataTypeContent, $dataType);
    } else {
        // If Model doesn't exist, get data from table name
        $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([DB::table($dataType->name), $getter]);
        $model = false;
    }

    // Check if BREAD is Translatable
    if (($isModelTranslatable = is_bread_translatable($model))) {
        $dataTypeContent->load('translations');
    }

    // Check if server side pagination is enabled
    $isServerSide = isset($dataType->server_side) && $dataType->server_side;

    // Check if a default search key is set
    $defaultSearchKey = $dataType->default_search_key ?? null;

    $view = 'voyager::bread.browse';

    if (view()->exists("voyager::$slug.browse")) {
        $view = "voyager::$slug.browse";
    }

    return Voyager::view($view, compact(
        // dd($dataType),
        'dataType',
        'dataTypeContent',
        'isModelTranslatable',
        'search',
        'orderBy',
        'orderColumn',
        'sortOrder',
        'searchable',
        'isServerSide',
        'defaultSearchKey',
        'usesSoftDeletes',
        'showSoftDeleted'
    ));
}
```

I have changed the model query `$query=$model::select('id','owner_name');`
which gives me proper single column data on view but still all the column headings are displayed on view.

Below is the `thead` view code.

```
 <thead>
  <tr>
    @can('delete',app($dataType->model_name))
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" class="select_all">
    </th>
    @endcan
    @foreach($dataType->browseRows as $row)
    <th>
      @if ($isServerSide)
      <a href="{{ $row->sortByUrl($orderBy, $sortOrder) }}">
        @endif
        {{ $row->display_name }}
        @if ($isServerSide)
        @if ($row->isCurrentSortField($orderBy))
        @if ($sortOrder == 'asc')
        <i class="voyager-angle-up pull-right"></i>
        @else
        <i class="voyager-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        @endif
        @endif
      </a>
      @endif
    </th>
    @endforeach
    <th class="actions text-right">{{ __('voyager::generic.actions') }}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this can help you or not, but this is how I do it. First, you must create a database using Voyager UI, then add bread. This method doesn't involved in coding at all. After creating database and add bread, head to tools->bread to see the page. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw4tD.png

After that, scroll down and find the table that contains such column and click edit bread.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAKz4.png

Then, scroll down to find the column you want to include. If you want the column, in this instance (ID), to be shown in header, check the box for browse in visibility. If you don't want, just uncheck it. The same goes for other columns. After you are done, scroll down to the bottom of the page and click submit. With that, you will be able to customize the header of the table. https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0XE5.png

https://voyager.devdojo.com/academy/ This is the tutorial by Voyager. The video explains how you can customize the table header almost at the end. You can also check the documentations provided by Voyager to know more. You can also learn how to create database and add bread in the documentation.